# confusion between post and get method

Tags: java, rest, post, get, development-environment

I'm creating an API which accepts `customerid`, `account number` and `date` as json objects and returns a file whose location is mentioned in the database corresponding to it.

I'm confused about which method I need to use: GET OR POST. I am still learning to create APIs.

Comment: have you try "difference between GET and POST" on google ?. The simpliest would be "GET is used for viewing something, without changing it, while POST is used for changing something". A query in the browser URL input is a GET.

Comment: @azro Thank you, I read that but i was not clear about using it. I think it will help.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are trying to Query and Fetch something.  GET is a good choice.

```
REST Verb   Action
- - - - - - - - - - 
GET         Fetches a record or set of resources from the server
OPTIONS     Fetches all available REST operations
POST        Creates a new set of resources or a resource
PUT         Updates or replaces the given record
PATCH       Modifies the given record
DELETE      Deletes the given resource
```

The detailed explain or guide, you can refer to:
https://hevodata.com/learn/rest-api-best-practices/

Comment: I am not creating anything, i am just fetching file from the location given in the database.

Comment: OK.  Looks like you are querying something and then fetch a file content with the location queried from the database?  
If so,  it's a GET action.  You need use GET request.
If you want to learn REST related information,  the above link can be a start.