# Spring CrudRepository

Tags: spring, crud

I am trying to implement all basic CRUD operations using Spring and CrudRepository. I have already implemented GET, POST, DELETE, PUT but I want also to implement PATCH. Does Crud Repository supports HTTP PATCH? Because so far I haven't find any method of CrudRepository that implements that.

Answer (score 0):

When you check the HTTP PATCH,
PATCH means: Modifies the given record

If you want to implement it, you just need call the Update API of your CrudRepository in your Service/Controller class with the PATCH method.

But in mordern REST API implementation,  we seldom use this. Most USE PUT instead.

For the several REST part,  you can refer to:
[confusion between post and get method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238765/confusion-between-post-and-get-method/72238803#72238803)

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have tried using the update method of CrudRepository but it doesn't work. If my entity has lets say 4 fields, I want to update using PATCH only 1 field and when I pass 1 field only in update then it returns an error.

Comment: Please show us the code in your original question,  then we might be able to dig more. 
What's the error showing?